# Ember.js 2.7 - How to check validation on an input field?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm pretty new to Ember.js and I'm having trouble how to do a validation on a certain input field.

Here is the code for my template index.hbs:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1>Coming Soon</h1>

  <br/><br/>

  <p>Don't miss our launch date, request an invitation now.</p>

  <div class="form-horizontal form-group form-group-lg row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-5 col-md-offset-2">
      {{input type="email" value=model.email class="form-control" placeholder="Please type your e-mail address." autofocus="autofocus"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <button disabled={{isDisabled}} {{action 'saveInvitation' model}} class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Request invitation</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{#if responseMessage}}
    <div class="alert alert-success">{{responseMessage}}</div>
  {{/if}}
  <br/><br/>
</div>
```

and here is the code from my controller index.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  headerMessage: 'Coming soon',
  responseMessage: '',
  email: '',

  isValid: Ember.computed.match('email', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
  isDisabled: Ember.computed.not('isValid'),
});
```

The input field that I want to get validation for is the email one. I know how to go about the validation by replacing the value="" field to just value="email", but I want to know how I can do it using the value=model.email

This seems like an easy problem, but I can't find anything on the docs about this particular issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `input` helper this will update `model.email` property when you type in text field.

1.You dont need to declare `email` property in controller.
2.`isValid` computed property dependent key should be `model.email`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  headerMessage: 'Coming soon',
  responseMessage: '',

  isValid: Ember.computed.match('model.email', /^.+@.+\..+$/),
  isDisabled: Ember.computed.not('isValid'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the validity of email inside `saveInvitation` action.